# Running sqlite command inside of shell

Tags: sqlite, wscript.shell

I am trying to run sqlite3 from command prompt remotely through a jscript. I am using a shell to start the database and it does. However any commands after that do not work.

```js
var oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
var ret = oShell.Run('cmd.exe /k cd c:\\sqlite && sqlite3 G:\\qpp.db; && sqlite3 qpp.db .show', 1 /* SW_SHOWNORMAL */, true/* bWaitOnReturn */);
```

Comment: var ret = oShell.Run('cmd.exe /k cd c:\\sqlite && sqlite3 G:\\qpp.db < G:\\test.sql', 1 /* SW_SHOWNORMAL */, true/* bWaitOnReturn */);  This works but I don't want to have to write a file for every import. Can this be done without using a file??

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ret = oShell.Run('cmd.exe /k cd c:\\sqlite && echo .import "H:\\\\2019\\\\00028-000-19\\\\QPPData\\\\Directory_Proofs\\\\Index_007.txt" test | sqlite3.exe G:\\qpp.db', 1 /* SW_SHOWNORMAL */, true/* bWaitOnReturn */);
```

```js
(echo .mode tabs) >%USERPROFILE%\.sqliterc
```

Comment: So I add a rescource file that changes the default of the option to tabs. Then my shell command runs the import.